# How to secure htdocs files with php?

Tags: htdocs

I want to secure htdoc file so that none can access into htdocs . How is it possible?

How I rewrite it?

```
<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this into a `.htaccess` file placed directly into the htdocs folder:

```
Order allow, deny
Deny from all
```

Comment: where is my .htaccess. I am using Xampp.

Comment: `.htaccess` files are used to configure certain Apache settings on a directory level. They don’t exist by default, you need to create one.